# Microsoft quantum Development Kit with another PC

Tags: quantum-computing, q#

I think that quantum teleportation can be realized by the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit, but by placing one piece of data (name A) on a PC not connected to the Internet and acting on one side (name B) Is it possible to react experimentally?

In the sample code, I do not feel realized just by comparing two variables in one code in one PC.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Microsoft's Quantum Development Kit is focused on making it easier to write programs that act on stationary qubits such as topological qubits built using Majorana fermions. In that context, teleportation is a useful procedure for moving information around inside a single quantum device.

That said, you are quite right in that teleportation can also be used to transfer quantum states between distinct quantum devices — qubits such as polarization modes of photons that are used in such procedures are often called "flying qubits" to distinguish from stationary qubits. If you're interested in quantum networking protocols such as quantum key distribution that focus on what you can do by sending flying qubits, I'd recommend looking at the [SimulaQron](http://www.simulaqron.org/) project. Their [implementation of teleportation](https://stephaniewehner.github.io/SimulaQron/PreBetaDocs/ExamplespythonLibTeleport.html) can be run on two distinct classical computers that share a classical network connection to simulate sending flying qubits.